# D3 - Stacked bar chart dual axis with line chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-stacked-trend-bar-positioned-months-4sqvwd?embed=1&file=src/app/bar-chart.ts&hideNavigation=1

I'm using D3 to create a stacked bar chart in Angular

I now also need to have a line graph on the same chart.

I think the best way to do this is with a dual axis.

I have the second axis working but can't get the line to work.

Can anyone point me the direction to get this working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `line` function (**valueline** in your case) doesn't seem like its defined correctly as it's missing the accessor functions. Here are the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#line_x) for the same.

I couldn't fork your code but here's a snippet (containing the drawLine method) you can try:

```
private drawLine(linedata:any){
  var that = this;
  var valueline = d3.line().x(function(d, i) { 
    return that.x1(d.date); 
   // return that.x0(d.date) + 0.5 * that.x0.bandwidth();
  }).y(function(d) { 
    return that.y1(d.value); 
  });

  this.x1.domain(this.data.map((d:any)=>{
    return d.date
  }));

  this.y1.domain(d3.extent(linedata, function(d) { 
    return d.value 
  }));

  this.lineArea.append("path")
    .data([linedata])
    .attr("class", "line").style('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr("d", valueline);
}
```

It works and I also have included a commented line for the `x` attribute which matches the way you're offsetting the bars. And another suggestion would be to use the same `x0` scale as the newly defined `x1` has the same domain as `x0`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I suggest to use `return that.x0(d.date) + 0.5 * that.x0.bandwidth();` so the line points coincide with the axis ticks

Comment: Thanks @rioV8. I didn't think much of the offset. Anyway, edited the commented line.

Comment: Thanks Shashank - thats working now but the line always shows one value that is zero that isn't in the data, here Aug is zero but the data isn't - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-stacked-trend-bar-positioned-months-4sqvwd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts

Comment: It isn't zero but it's 100 for Aug and if you look at your second Y axis (right), you'll see that it extends from 100 to 450 which is nothing but the extent of the `linedata` which implies that the line is plotted correctly. Try changing the `y1` domain just for testing purposes to [0,500] i.e. `this.y1.domain([0,500])` and you'll notice the difference.